# Argument of type __ Incompatible with Parameter of type __

Tags: c++, arrays, function, c++11, struct

I'm a student in a college creating a small little stock market simulator game for a class. We were asked to specifically use structures as opposed to classes, which I'm more well-versed in.

I'm trying to set up an array of "Stock" structure objects, and am attempting to pass (either/or, both have failed) the array of Stock objects and the Stock objects themselves to a function, each in a separate file. This is the Stock structure.

```
struct Stock {
 string FullName;
 string Ticker;
 string Info;
 string Chairman;
 double Revenue;
 double AvgVol;
 double High52;
 double Low52;
 double CurrentPrice;
 Stock() {
     FullName = "";
     Ticker = "";
     Info = "";
     Chairman = "";
     Revenue = 0;
     AvgVol = 0;
     High52 = 0;
     Low52 = 0;
     CurrentPrice = 0;
 } };
```

This is in it's own file dedicated specifically for creating various structures used throughout the game.
This is how I attempt to create and call the stocks in the main driver function.

```
Stock Apple;
Stock Chipotle;
Stock Disney;
Stock Tesla;
Stock stockList[4] = { Apple, Chipotle, Disney, Tesla }; //Will access the stocks from this array from here on in
SetupStructs(stockList); //Function that creates the 4 company's information as struct objects to be utilized later
```

This is the SetupStructs function in a third file, dedicated specifically for functions, so as to not clog up the main file.

```
void SetupStructs(Stock stockList[]) {

stockList[0].FullName = "Apple Incorporated";

stockList[1].FullName = "Chipotle Mexican Grill Incorporated";

stockList[2].FullName = "Walt Disney Company";

stockList[3].FullName = "Tesla Motors Incorporated"; };
```

If it's not obvious, I've left 90% of the rest of the SetupStructs function out of what I pasted so as to not clog up the page with unnecessary code.

The problem is: "SetupStructs(stockList)" is throwing the error:

```
argument of type "Stock *" is incompatible with parameter of type "Stock *"
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is this error appearing? Apologies for the mini-essay.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Godbolt seems happy with a stripped down example: https://godbolt.org/g/Yu7P8N

Comment: @StephenNewell Visual Studio Community 2017. I downloaded whatever C++ games package is recommended to use when you first open up the application.

Comment: Godbolt seems fine with Visual Studio: https://godbolt.org/g/C2KKZB. Are you sure the example you provided fails?

Comment: @StephenNewell Well, it's one of 25 errors VS is currently throwing at me, and 24 of the 25 are all pertaining to my various usage of the struct object.

Comment: Here's a dumb question, do structures have to be in a header file? I currently have my struct objects being defined in a .cpp file. I never put a lot of thought into how I created classes but I always created 1 class per header file, and in this scenario, I'm creating multiple structs (which are pretty much classes from my understanding) in a .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm answering the question myself, I figured it out. I didn't think to put the struct object creation in a header file, and left it in a source file. Putting in a header file instead fixed the problems I was having. My mistake.